# Is it possible to delay the time a confirmation email is sent by a period of minutes or days?

Tags: cognito-forms, scheduling

Our uses for this would be:

(1) to wait five minutes after an initial confirmation email is sent to email a client a secondary link to edit their event information, and

(2) to send a confirmation email the day before a client's event date automatically.

Answer (score 2):

For the both use cases, you can set custom "when" to send conditions with the conditional logic builder.  You'll need a different notification email for each use case you've identified.

- For the delay of five minutes, set the *Send when Submitted* "When" condition to be 5 minutes later than the Entry.Submitted dateTime object.

  ```
  Now() = Entry.Submitted.AddMinutes(5)
  ```
- For the day in advance reminder, add a hidden field for the event start date; set the *Send when Submitted* "When" condition to be a day in advance of the event startDate field.

  ```
  Now() = StartDate.AddDays(-1)
  ```

For more about these types of calculations and Conditional Logic, see

- https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/2/calculations
- https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/conditional-logic

Note, you may need to further manipulate the reminder email as it may only be triggered to send exactly 24 hours before the start time of the event if your event start date field doesn't have a time associated with it (in which case it may default to midnight). Also, you'll want to factor in time-zone considerations for your reminder as well.  See [CognitoForms' help post about time zone handling](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/125/faq/how-is-time-zone-handled-for-date-or-time-values-like-entry-dates).